# Logic Manipulation of Arrays to Remove an Index

Tags: javascript, arrays, logic

I am trying to create a function that can manipulate arrays...

```
 var myArray = [2, 1, 1, 1, 1];
```

now I want it to be like this

> [3, 1, 1, 1]

now my function accepts 3 parameters

1. **ArrayToProcess** - well its the array that will be processed
2. **indexTarget** - this is the selected value that is defined by index
3. **morphToValue** - this is the value I want the selected value to become.

well my objective is to accept the indexTarget which for example

```
myFunction(myArray,0,3); //myArray is [2, 1, 1, 1, 1]
```

as you can see I want my function to loop over the `myArray` so it will try to add numbers in the array until it will reach the `morphToValue` so it became [3, 1, 1, 1], it purges the `2` on the first index and `1` on the second index to gain `3`. **It will just also minus any number on the array if it adds too much on the exceeding on the morphToValue**

another example will be like this I want the array

var myArray = [2, 1, 1, 1, 1];

to be like this

```
[2, 1, 3];
```

by doing call myFunction like this

```
myFunction(myArray,2,3);
```

how can I make this possible? I want also to continue iterating on the beginning again of the array if I will set **indexTarget** in the last index of the array so it would be like this

var myArray = [2, 1, 1, 1, 1];

it will become

```
[1, 1, 1, 3]; //when I invoke myFunction(myArray,4,3);
```

please put a comment if you don't understand something....

this is what I have tried so far http://jsfiddle.net/eESNj/

```
var myArray = ['2', '1', '1', '1', '1'];

indexPurge(myArray, 0, 3);

function indexPurge(haystack, indexTarget, morphToValue) {

    var toIntHaystack = [];

    for (var i = 0; i < haystack.length; i++) {
        toIntHaystack.push(parseInt(haystack[i]));
    }

    console.log(toIntHaystack); //before

    var i = 0;

    var purgedValue = 0;

    do {
        console.log(i + ' - ' + toIntHaystack[i]);
        purgedValue += toIntHaystack[i];
        toIntHaystack.splice(i, 1);
        if (purgedValue >= morphToValue) {
            break;
        }
        i++;
    } while (i < toIntHaystack.length);



    toIntHaystack.splice(indexTarget, 0, morphToValue); //after
    console.log(toIntHaystack);

}
```

Comment: Please show what you've tried, we're not here to do your work for you.

Comment: @Barmar I had re-edited my post I put it on a fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/eESNj/

Comment: Then this: `myFunction(myArray,0,3); //myArray is [2, 1, 1, 1, 1]` should it be like this? myFunction(myArray,0,2); //myArray is [2, 1, 1, 1, 1]`

Comment: Your fiddle appears to work for the first and third examples, you just need to fix the second.

Comment: @Barmar well I do have still a problem when you are trying to add numbers and you exceed on the sum required by the `morphToValue` any clues how can I solve it?

Comment: @Barmar can you give me a clue on how I can fix it for the second?

Comment: @Mahan try http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/7Wg5p/2/

Comment: "It will just also minus any number on the array if it adds to much on the exceeding on the morphToValue", Not sure to understand?

Comment: I'm struggling to understand this question.  Saying *why* you want to do this might help.

Comment: @kybernetikos see my answer below.. I already solved my problem =)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solved my own problem.. I hope this will help someone that wil have the same problem

http://jsfiddle.net/YUdJL/

```
var myarrayx =  [1,1,3]; //5

function morphArray(myarray, index, target){

    //accumulate value on the array to gain target value
    var accu = 0;
    for(var i = 0; i < myarray.length; i++){
        var thisIndex = myarray[i];
        for(var j = 0; j < thisIndex; j++){
            if(accu != target){
                myarray[i]--;  
                accu++;
            }
            else{
                break;
            }
        }
    }

    //remove the zeroes on the array
    for(var k = 0; k < myarray.length; k++){
        if(myarray[k] == 0){
            myarray.splice(k, 1);
        }
    }

    //check if the target index is still available
    if((myarray.length - 1) > index){
        //index is not available anymore.. just push it
        myarray.push(target);
    }
    else{
        //insert the element in the desired index
        myarray.splice(index, 0, target);
    }


    return myarray;
}

console.log('----'+morphArray(myarrayx, 0, 2));
```

Answer (score 2):

here is my variant, it should work faster then splice variant:

```
function fixIdx(idx, len) {
    return idx % len; 
}
function fixStartOffset(idx, len) {
    return (idx < len) ? 0 : (idx % len);
}
function morhArray(inputArray, startIndex, targetValue) {
    var l = inputArray.length;
    var sum = 0;
    var endIdx = 0;
    while ( (sum < targetValue) && (endIdx < l) )
        sum += inputArray[fixIdx(startIndex+endIdx++, l)];
    if (endIdx == l) return [sum];
    var outputArray = [];
    for (var i=fixStartOffset(startIndex+endIdx, l); i<startIndex; i++)
        outputArray.push(inputArray[i]);
    outputArray.push(sum);
    for (var i=startIndex+endIdx; i<l; i++)
        outputArray.push(inputArray[i]);
    return outputArray;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
var myArray = [2, 1, 1, 1, 1];

function myfunction(array, index, target) {
    var copy = array.slice(0);
    var c = 0,
        i = index;
    while (c < target && array.length) {
        c += copy.splice(i, 1)[0];
        if (i == array.length - 1) {
            i = 0;
        }
    }
    if (i == index) {
        copy[index] = c;
    } else {
        copy.push(c);
    }
    return copy;
}

console.log(myfunction(myArray, 0, 3));
console.log(myfunction(myArray, 2, 3))
console.log(myfunction(myArray, 4, 3))
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/7Wg5p/)

Comment: The third argument isn't a count. You're supposed to add elements until it reaches that total.